# Multiple UV mapping problem

Tags: uv

i'm new to blender.
I'm a bit confused on the concept of multiple uv mapping.

My workflow:
I made an object, a plane, and I wanted to assigned different materials and UV maps for the cockpit and the body.

- I made the seam
- Assigned each materials to its corresponding part (the cockpit and body)
- Unwrapped the cockpit
- Create new uv map
- Unwrapped the body

but as I select all, the uv map on the "body" still consist of the body itself and the cockpit
[image]
Then when I added texture and using the body and the texture overlapped.

What i want is different uv map and different image texture for each part.
Please help I've been stucked with this problem for 3 days..

**Update**
I've tried to separate the object, made its own uv maps for the body and the cockpit, and I joined them again. But then each uv map only show the texture assigned to it and not both applied/showed in object mode/texture paint
[image]
and when I exported it to obj file and open it on papercraft program, the texture shown is the uv map that set as active for rendering

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Make two materials (body and cockpit), one UV map : mark a seam at the materials limit. Unwrap.  Assign the needed faces to each material. Set a texture per material. Adjust each of your UV map part to each texture (they can overlap but each part will be used by one material).

Comment: May work (to try) : duplicate the object. Remove the second UV map from the original, remove the first UV map from the copy. Rename the UV map of the copy with the same name as the first UV map. Join original and copy. Remove double vertices. You may now have all in a single UV map and at the same place (not tested, so make copies before trying).

Comment: To clarify what @lemon said... You need to give different materials to the cockpit and body, then assign those materials to the faces of your object where you want them to apply. After that, you assign your textures to the materials, select the faces you want to uv-unwrap, and adjust your uv map in the uv editor as needed. Both materials can use the same texture file and be mapped to different areas of it.

Comment: @lemon i've done your first advise in the first place, but while I was texture painting, the uv wrap of the other part bother me. As for your second advice, that's not what I want. I want the cockpit and the body have their own image texture, and it means different uv map.
thanks for your help though

Comment: @AnthonyForwood what I want is two texture file for each part, thanks though

Comment: Robby, there is a misunderstanding : 1 UV map is needed for these 2 materials, and each material correspond to some faces only (assign these faces to the materials in edit mode). Then each material uses one texture. So all is ok (you do not need two UV maps). If you want me to write an answer about it, please upload your file.

Comment: @lemon oh I see, but what about those gaming 3d model that has more than one uv maps? In papercraft, it's in pdo file (pepakura) they have changeable texture which has its own uv mapping, so I assume they have multiple uv maps.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8XSilWOVFofQjR2b1VOLTNFZm8
that's my blender file, I really appreciate your help lemon, thanks

Comment: oh... ok... just added an answer... but I have a look at your file (tell if the explanations are ok, please, in meantime)

Comment: But Robby, your file is good now !! Do you need anything more from that ?

Answer (score 1):

Example : we have a plane and want to 3 materials based on two textures.

Plane parts :

- The cockpit : glossy material with texture 1
- The nose : diffuse material also with texture 1
- The other parts : diffuse material with texture 2

[image]

- Create your plane
- Add the three materials
- In edit mode, select the wanted faces and assign them to the corresponding material

[image]

- Create your UV seams (probably corresponding to the material). You may also have done the seams before the material assignation

[image]

- Select the wanted parts using the "*select*" button of the material,
- Then UV unwrap

[image]

- The materials can be defined as you wish (here I used a bake to produce the textures
- You can also export the UV map parts separately in order to paint over it in the tool you want (or paint directly here in Blender)

Comment: Allright I get it now, and I've figured out the problem on the other program.
You've been very helpful thankyou lemon :)